# solr schema.xml validate

Tags: xml, solr

I have a problem with the schema validation of Solr, shows a 500 error.

```
SimplePostTool: version 1.4
SimplePostTool: POSTing files to http://localhost:8081/solr-project/update..
SimplePostTool: POSTing file sample-solr.xml
SimplePostTool: FATAL: Solr returned an error #500 Error Interno del Servidor
```

The field of schema.xml of **Solr** is this:

```
 <field>
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="url" type="string" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content" type="text_es" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 </field>
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

No need to follow an order equal to the schema.xml, **id** is field **required**.

**sample-solr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <add>
      <doc>
       <field name="id">id product</field>
       <field name="url">http://www.web.com/content/direct/index.html</field>
       <field name="content">field content text</field> 
     </doc>
    </add>
```

Compile project and execute by test:

```
~/opt/solr/solr/example/exampledocs$ java -jar -Durl=http://localhost:8081/solr-project/update post.jar sample-solr.xml
```

What can be?. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Solr 4+, have a look at the console where you started Solr or in Admin Web UI under logs screen. The real message is on the server side and will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I can not see what the version, I get error 400, I configured tomcat on port 8081, could that be the problem?.


if I try to see this URL into your browser:

http://localhost:8081/solr-project/update


the response is:

**HTTP 400 - missing content stream**

Comment: You should know which version of Solr you are running. If you are running from localhost, you must have installed it. And your admin URL should be in your solr.xml file, try pinging that. If you have real troubles, try running the example in the distribution and starting the tests there.

Comment: the version is 3.6.2.

Estado HTTP 404 - missing core name in path, testing localhost:8081/solr-project/ this is OK, but localhost:8081/solr-project/admin is the problem.

Comment: already solved. tomcat (conf / Catalina / localhost) contained no solr-project.xml file. Thanks!.

Comment: the version Solr is:
Lucene Specification Version: 3.6.2

the error is #500. SimplePostTool: FATAL: Solr returned an error #500